# Can I assign the special IP address when I use wget?

Tags: linux, wget

I have a multi-IP addresses Server, a main IP 102.1.1.1 and a C segment 103.1.1.0/24 IP addresses on it.

when I use

```
wget www.google.com
```

can I assign my special ip address in my Server like `ping`?
if can not, why?

Comment: Please Read The Fine Manual 

[`man wget`](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Download-Options) 

Does your version also offer a switch / option to select a specific IP-address / interface / device name ?


If your wget version does not, consider the similar `curl` command [`man curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option to force `wget` to use a specific address on the local host:

```
--bind-address=ADDRESS
```

So you would do something like that:

```
wget www.google.com --bind-address=102.1.1.1
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use --bind-address=ADDRESS
(for example

```
wget https://www.example.com/ --bind-address=123.123.123.123
```

Or add IP and Domain to file /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1               localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
 ::1             localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
 123.123.123.123          www.example.com
```

This file check before DNS Server, if you assign an IP to a Domain, your domain will be resolve from that IP address and no matter what DNS is.

Comment: You have not understood what either the bind address is for or what the hosts file is for.